# Flutter IconButton splashRadius theme

Tags: flutter

How to change the splash Radius for all Icon buttons from the app theme not individually like this

```
IconButton(
onPressed: (){},
icon: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down_rounded),
splashRadius: 20,
),
```

Answer (score 3):

According to documentation :

> If null, default splash radius of Material.defaultSplashRadius is
> used.

You can't get it from a Theme : it's either the individual setting, either a Material constant.